# Advanced IIS tutorials or scenario based learning

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6, iis-8

Please anyone can provide me website link for IIS advanced tutorial or youtube channels where I can get complete knowledge about IIS

Comment: While there might be great books and tutorials out there you can find from search engines, I don't believe anything can give you "complete knowledge about IIS". Even Microsoft internal trainings given to new support engineers dedicated to IIS won't cover all aspects and those guys need to be mentored and trained through working with customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best IIS learning tutorial is [Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-web-server-overview) on IIS. I have read other blogs about IIS, but the content is not systematic and not as complete as the official documentation.

After all, IlS is a basic Internet service based on Microsoft Windows provided by Microsoft. It is the only official Web server on the Microsoft Windows platform, so the content covered by the official documents is also the most comprehensive.

In addition, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/) is about the function and structure of various elements of the IIS configuration file, which can be learned together with the official documentation.

Hope my answer helps you.